# Why is a string Array causing a LNK2001 error?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, std, lnk2001

I am mainly a C# programmer but I need this project done in C++ so I may be missing something for C++ arrays.

I have a DLL I have been working on, witch is working and connected into the project that handles the User Interface.  In the DLL I am trying to make a logger class so I can debug info out into the interface.  But when I try using a string array I get a LNK2001 error.  Bellow is my header file for the class.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Logger
{
public:
    static string& GetLog();
    static void Log(string message);
private:
    static const int maxLogs = 1000;
    static string logs[maxLogs];
};
```

IF I remove the string array the error is gone but I need a way to store my log messages

Comment: Did you initialize `logs` anywhere?

Comment: You need to define a static member not just declare it.

Comment: Never use "using namespace std;" in a header file is common good practice.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know it was bad practice changing it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `static` member variable must be *defined* (exactly once), that is only a *declaration* within the class defintion. In exactly one `.cpp` file add:

```
std::string Logger::logs[Logger::maxLogs];
```

---

Suggest reading [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Thanks this worked.  and thanks for the suggest reading Learning more is always welcome :)